# Transform a rectangle to create an effect of depth

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, blend

I want to create a transform animation to change the shape of a rectangle in WPF. The top right and top left corners have to be pulled together as in the following example image.

[image]

What transform properties should I use to achieve this effect?

Comment: This is known as perspective - perhaps this CodePlex project will help: http://perspective.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the 3D animation to achieve this ,If right and left corners are shrink-ed  into same sizes... You may refer the below for more details..

http://wpftution.blogspot.in/2012/05/3d-image-animation-in-wpf-using-blend-4.html

There are resources for 3D animation..

Comment: This effect might work for an image, but that is not what I am trying to achieve. I would like to apply this to a canvas, so that every item inside the canvas is skewed inward at the top.

Answer (score 0):

In expression blend : In rotation property set `X = -45`, `Y = 0`, `Z = 0`.

Rotation property can be found under Transform -->Projection --> Rotation.

For your reference you can check the article [Using the 3D tools to animate in Blend](http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/14/using-the-3d-tools-to-animate-in-blend/)